# Using PCA outputs to train corner features by Neural Network

Tags: matlab, opencv, neural-network, classification, pca

I am working on a project for vehicle classification where I have **N** images of a particular car and each of whose around **40** Corners/Edges Have been detected and stored in a matrix say `MAT[40x2]` .
So I created a `Nx(40x2)` matrix say **NMAT**

Now I have no Idea how to use this 3D matrix as a input to `pca(mat)` or `princomp(mat)` function.

However I know what pca is and how its calculations are made but All I don't know is how to use it.

***So can anyone provide me a quick walk-through***

Also PCA returns Eigen_Values,Eigen_Vectors and Principal Components after using matlab pca function along with some other data.

But as Neural Network only takes a **vector** and not the **matrix** as a input then what should be fed to NN after some data has been retrieved using pca function? (I don't know how to use those principal components to create a 1D feature vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `reshape` it into a 2D matrix with `N` rows and 80 cols so each image is modelled as a point in a 80-dimensional space whose dimensionality you want to reduce.  From the ANN point of view, it does not matter that the inputs have a 'natural' 2-dimensional layout. That information is not processed by the ANN so it can be 'destroyed'.

As for the second part of your question, the ANN takes a vector input, indeed, but it needs several of them to be trained so the training function most probably takes a matrix of inputs. That matrix is the product between your data matrix and the principal components you selected from the `pca` according to their corresponding eigen values.

That was a quick, high-level, walkthrough...

Comment: So by reshape you mean I need to convert a 2-D array of coordinates say A=[2,3;4,6;5,9;7,1] to a new 1-D array Narr=[2,3,4,6,5,9,7,1]?

Comment: Yes. That would be the feature vector associated to one image. reshape is the name of the Matlab function to do that.

Comment: So what I understood uptill now is that in this way I get a matrix **imageMat[Nx80]** So its my data matrix and I calculate its principal components using matlab pca function or whatsoever and put them in a matrix say **compMat[]** and then multiply `imageMat*compMat` to create a new matrix **trainMat[]** and then use this trainMat as input to NN

Comment: Yes. The imageMat*compMat part is the projection of the data on the principal component subspace. Note that you need to prune some columns from compMat to keep only the ones associated with the highest eigen values so that the projected data lives in a lower-dimensioal space than the original one. Otherwise, there is no point in computing the pca ; it is just a change of coordinates of the data space.

Comment: Yeah I learned that I am supposed to use only first k principal components with maximum variances,so is there any method to find K or its hit and trial type method ?

Comment: You typically use a [scree plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) and observe the percentage of 'information' (variance) that is kept as a funcition of k when retaining the k principal components (those are ordered by their corresponding eigen values)

Comment: Well thanks for helping me so deeply...gotta check this out :)